# Call to javascript from code behind doesn't work with ajax control UpdatePanelAnimationExtender

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm calling a javascript function from my C# code behind with:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "CallJSFunction", "JSFunction();", true);
```

My javascript is the following:

```
function JSFunction() {
    document.getElementById('ABC').scrollIntoView(true);
}
```

But the javascript is not being executed when I call it from code behind because there's an ajax control UpdatePanelAnimationExtender in my ascx code. Is there a way to get around this? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: what errors do you see in your browsers developer tools console? Perhaps the call to JSFunction is attempted before the function exists

Answer (score 0):

Try registering your UpdatePanel (assuming you are using one since you are using the extender). It probably cant find it since its buried in your update panel, not the Page.

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanelName, UpdatePanel.GetType(), "CallJSFunction", "JSFunction();", true);
```